# How do I autoresize an image, but at the top of the ImageView (programmatically in Xcode)?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, scaling, contentmode

I have an imageView (say 100x100) that I want to fill with a (smaller) image (say 50x10) and I want the image to go at the **top of the view**, not at the middle of the view.

If I use

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

it fills the view with the image scaled at 100x20 (as expected) but in the middle of the view.

Like this:

```
+---------+
|         |
|i m a g e| <---my image (scaled)
|         |
+---------+ <---my UIImageView
```

If I set

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop | UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

I get this:

```
+---------+
|  image  | <---my image (not scaled)
|         |
|         |
+---------+
```

The image is **not** scaled and it stays at 50x10 in the middle of the imageView (as instructed by the UIViewContentModeTop, but it ignores UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit).

How do I get it to accept **both**? Like this:

```
+---------+
|i m a g e|
|         |
|         |
+---------+
```

Comment: This is sadly a far more difficult problem then it should be. You are only allowed to use 1 content mode for a `UIView`, so you have to choose what works best. I would say leave it on `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, and just re-centre the image based on where you want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be the worst solution but it works, You should set the frame of your image view first and then call this method.

```
-(void)adjustImageViewWithImageDimension:(CGRect)frame{
    UIImageView *tempView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    tempView.image = self.image;
    tempView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    tempView.clipsToBounds = false;
    CGFloat oldAlpha = self.alpha;
    self.alpha = 1;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempView.bounds.size);
    [tempView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.alpha = oldAlpha;
    self.image = resultingImage;
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is (almost) the way I went at the end. (I don't understand why you do it like that (since you are using UIGraphics) and not just fix a new image with size as the UIImageView frame and the original image at rendered at the top scaled ("manually") according to the ratio of the 2 widths (imageView & image) and then place that image in the imageView with no scaling needed, but both ways work.)