# iOS autolayout - gap between image and top of the screen, despite constraints set

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I have an image that i would like to place in the top part of the screen. I've set its mode to aspect fit, because i want to preserve original ratio. I've also set left, top and right constraints to 0:

[image]

Despite the fact that the top constraint is set to 0, there is a lot of empty space between the image and top of the screen which is definitely not what i want:

[image]

Only when i set top constraint to about "-100" i get something similar to what i would like to achieve:

[image]

Could you please explain me such non intuitive behaviour and tell me what should i do to place the image on the top of the screen without any gaps - like on the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trials an errors i come up with something that is 99% of what i originally wanted. Left, top and right constraint has to be set to 0, aspect ratio constraint also has to be enabled. On top of that "Scale to fill" mode. This works quite well besides that fact that you have to calculate the correct image ratio on your own.

Comment: Have you tried this on the different phone resultions? Esp iPhone 4 (3:2 ration) versus iPhone 5/6/6+ (16:9 ration) versus iPad (4:3 ratio) which have different aspect ratios. With scale to fill, you might find that you end up stretching or pinching the image on some devices unless you code for the different aspect ratios. You may be ok with it stretching/shrinking though slightly. You can overcome some of this on iPhone versus iPad by using size classes and setting the aspect ratio constraint to be different for Compact width versus Regular width. This leaves the issue of iPhone 4 v 5/6/6+.

Comment: Thanks Rory, i took that into account.

Answer (score 2):

This is worth a try, if you are still having this issue.

Tap on your ViewController and then uncheck the below properties. See if that fixes the problem.

[image]

Comment: Worth a try, I wasn't sure if maybe you had the images in a tableView or some other object that is affected by these settings. I guess it must be auto-layout related. ;(

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from your screenshot your image frame is much bigger than the image content. In case you want to have that frame consider setting `Aspect Fill` to image mode. Otherwise you should set following constraints: [image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: Maybe there is a space in your image itself?

Comment: No, thats not the case. Please take a look at my latest answer, its a slightly modified solution of yours and it solves the problem.

Comment: This helped me enormously! Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem this is not that easy to solve: [How do I autoresize an image, but at the top of the ImageView (programmatically in Xcode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314018/how-do-i-autoresize-an-image-but-at-the-top-of-the-imageview-programmatically)

Problem is you really want aspect fill and top at the same time.

My suggestion would be to take your UIImageView and add a cosnstraint for the aspect ratio as well as what you already have. Then Ctrl-drag from this constraint into the .h file of your view controller and create an IBOutlet.

This gives you an IBOutlet you can use in your code to adjust the aspect ratio of the UIImageView.

When you load your image in the code, inspect the image and calculate its aspect ratio. Set the constraint IBOutlet constant to match. This should then force the UIImageView to align itself aspect ration wise with the image and the constrains should then pull it all into place.

Comment: Thanks but it seems a little bit overcomplicated for me. Honestly speaking i haven't checked if it works yet. I still belive there is a more straighforward solution. Otherwise i would be very dissapointed with ios autolayout feature. I think that the problem i described is pretty common...

Comment: Auto layout works great. Your problem is you are wanting layout of a scaled images position inside a view which is bigger than your scaled image. There seems to be no settings saying to put a scaled image at the top, left, bottom, right of the view containing it etc... Hence I think you need to adjust the image views aspect ratio to match your image and then it will all layout fine.

Comment: You are right, it seems complicated and somebody may have a better way.